# How to rank array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I tried searching using many different keywords but I'm unable to get the result I'm looking for.

I've created a table with five values as such: 10, 3, 5, 4, 2
I have a row on top of the table which shows the rank.

So, above 10, it should say "5"
Above 3, it should say "2"
Above 5, it should say "4"
Above 4, it should say "3"
Above 2, it should say "1"

I can take care of the tabular column. It is the main script that I don't understand.

I thought I can create a duplicate array of the original one and sort the duplicate - Then compare both original and duplicate to rank them. It turns out that when I sort the duplicate array, the original is also sorted.

I thought I can create 2 duplicate arrays and not touch the original one. It still sorts all of the arrays. How can I do this then?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for how to `clone` or `deep copy` an array. When you do something like:

```
var a = [5,4,3,2,1]
var b = a;
```

Array `b` is set to refer to array `a`. If you, however, take a slice or do something else to get a copy of the data (not something refering to the actual structure), you can clone the array. So something like:

```
var a = [5,4,3,2,1]
var b = a.slice(0);
```

will give you an array `b` that won't change if you change `a`. See articles like [this](https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the array using [**spread**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). From there you can do a simple `sort()` to get the rank you're trying to achieve:

```js
const arr = [10, 3, 5, 4, 2];
const sortedArr = [...arr].sort((a,b) => a > b);

console.log(sortedArr);
```